# Process flow of Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

How the Informatica power center platform works? Like when we create a new user , what all background works processing? How the source data is getting extracted?

Is there any documents to get the background process of Informatica Power Center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ETL tool so, it extracts data form source, get it into infa server, does transformations, then push the data into target box. All these are done using multiple threads, you may not able to see them in documentation but you can see them into session logs. 
For a simple SRC> EXP>AGG>TGT type i can explain the back end process.
Step 1 - Infa gets the mappping info from Repo.
Step 2 - 
Infa service creates three threads -
 a. Read - reads from source and laods into infa memory.
 b. Transform - Aggregates data when #1 is done and put into memory.
 c. Load data to target when #2 is done.

This can be complex when you have many transformations. Everything is logged into session logs and you will get tons of info from that.

Answer (score 0):

Power Center Informatica offers the capability to connect  & fetch data from different heterogeneous source and processing of data. For example, You can connect to any database like SQL Server Database or Oracle database and can integrate the data into a third system. Informatica has its own transformation language that you can use in our expression transformation, filter transformation, source qualifier transformation etc. It is quite versatile and not at all difficult to learn, if you're familiar with any of the most popular programming languages of today.